# How to change elements of array without loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I would like to change all elements of array (for example `arr[i] +=1`), but I want to do it more efficiently, without `for-loop`.

My `for-loop` implementation:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] += 1
}

console.log(arr)
// arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: If they were all the same value you could use `arr.fill()`. But there's nothing built-in that does what you want, the loop is the only way.

Comment: "*I want to do it more efficiently, without `for-loop`*" why is a for loop inefficient?

Comment: You still need to do a loop. It is either going to be a for loop or a built in method like each or map which will loop for you internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ESX using `map()` or `reduce()` methods.

Your math function:

```
const mathFunction = (a) => ++a
```

`map()` method

```
arr = arr.map(it => mathFunction(it))
```

`reduce()` method

```
arr = arr.reduce((acc, rec) => acc.concat(mathFunction(rec)), [])
```

Comment: `arr = arr.map(it => mathFunction(it))` could be `arr = arr.map(mathFunction)
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()`

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = arr.map(x => x + 1);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I'm sure that you know, but strictly speaking, this is *less efficient* instead of *more efficient* because it allocates a 2nd array.

Comment: @PeterB 2nd array is optional. You could just reassign the first variable. Check the edited answer.\

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

```
const arrElementsPlusOne = arr.reduce((acc, nmb) => [ ...acc, nmb + 1 ], []);
```

You will get **immutable** array.